# Displaying a large number of records from WCF in a DataGridView with locator

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, entity-framework, pagination

I have this Clarion TPS based business software which I want to replace with the software I have written in C#, using the folllowing technologies:

- SQL Server 2008 R2 Express
- EntityFramework 4
- WCF Service with wsHttpBinding and message-based security using UserNamePassword credentials
- Windows Forms clients

[Clarion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarion_%28programming_language%29) software uses TPS files as database tables. TPS Database file uses an [ISAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISAM) file format allowing all indexes and multiple data files to be contained in one disk file. The advantage of this approach is very fast record access, however the major disadvantages are high possibility of database corruption when accessed by multiple clients and high possibility of having inconsistent data in your tables.

I want to replace it because I want to have a better control over my database access (e.g. who can access what), I don't want to allow clients to access the database directly among other things and I found WCF Service to be perfect for the task.

This is all good in theory, however the real usage scenario drew me back from implementing it for now. For example, when I open a dialog with Datagridview which needs to show a relatively large list of records (some 20.000) it takes ~10 seconds to show. In Clarion, it happens instantly. There is a feature in Clarion called "Locator" which allows you to locate the record by typing those letters that record property (eg. Name) begins with.

I am aware that serialization and deserialization of data over WCF requires some time. As for serialization, I have optimized the code so WCF Service uses **DataContractSerializer** (with Cyclic references aware behavior). I have changed the default entities generated by EF to POCO entities, using EF POCO Entity generator. I have added precompiled views and my WCF service is returning objects known as "ViewModels" instead of POCOs where I thought it's required.

I have created something that's similar to that Clarion's "locator" behavior and it looks like this:

```
private void locator_TextChanged(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(locator.Text))
    {
        for (int idx = 0; idx <= dataGrid1.RowCount - 1; idx++)
        {
            var row = dataGrid1.Rows[idx];
            if ((row.DataBoundItem != null) && ((SomeViewModel)row.DataBoundItem).Name.ToUpper().StartsWith(locator.Text.ToUpper()))
            {
                row.Cells[0].Selected = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine with few hundred, even couple thousands records. But looks and feels awful with large number of records. As you might have guessed when you saw the code. It doesn't work any faster this way either:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(locator.Text)) {
    var r = dataGrid1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().FirstOrDefault(x => ((SomeViewModel)(x.DataBoundItem)).PrezimeIme.ToUpper().StartsWith(locator.Text.ToUpper()));
    if (r != null) 
    {
        r.Cells[0].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

The question. How to mimic that Clarion's fast data loading of so many records into the datagridview if we know that I use those technologies I listed above?

Answer (score 0):

Clarion TPS files don't get corrupted when multiple programs access them because they use a  file locking protocol. This can get messed up if they're access through file shared that use opportunistic locking (oplocks) because the order of lock/unlock might get skewed, or if you have any clients that run Microsoft Security Essentials (it has a "feature" that mix the order of lock/unlock, and no, it won't be fixed), but otherwise it works "well".

The reason your code is slow is because it has to itterate throug all the rows in the file, and this is slow since it's all disk I/O and Clarion doesn't do any caching.

To access the data you can:
1) Convert your TPS files to CVS using [this tool](http://www.ctrl-alt-dev.nl/Projects/TPS-to-CSV/TPS-to-CSV.html) and import them into your SQL database. This has prevously been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152886/convert-from-tps-to-csv/22203355).

2) Buy the TPS-ODBC driver from SoftVelocity and access the TPS files through SQL queries. The TPS driver has some quirks, you need a function to convert date and time, you can't access large dims, some queries might return less rows than the TPS files contains (depends on how your primary key is constructed), and you must have a unique primary key in all the files. This is as fast/slow as accessing the files directly, so I would reccomend only using this method to export the data to your MSSQL database.

There are also several tools that can convert you Clarion DCT to SQL by exporting the DCT to a text file (dtcx), and you can also make Clarion generate the structure by changing the table type from TPS to MSSQL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your helpful links. Accessing the TPS data was not an issue. I was able to export data from Clarion TPS using TopScan application, and even access that data from C# directly using some TPS ODBC Driver which comes bundled with Clarion 5. Making user experience in WinForms similar to that in Clarion was an issue.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are looping through all records but Clarion code gets a new position from file index.